# Gun is moving up and down with fps camera in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have downloaded my standard assests from unity 2017.1.4.But when i connect my gun with fps camera that gun is also moving up and down with the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand your problem but if you want to lock the object in place use:

```
    Vector3 pos;
    Quaternion rot;
    private void Awake()
    {
        pos = gameObject.transform.position;
        rot = gameObject.transform.rotation;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = pos;
        gameObject.transform.rotation = rot;
    }
```

or even better this to set it from the editor:

```
    [SerializeField] Vector3 pos;
    [SerializeField] Quaternion rot;
    private void Update()
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = pos;
        gameObject.transform.rotation = rot;
    }
```

If this wasn't it try to provide more information on your problem

Dont worry about the downvotes it happens even in the best families

Comment: First up all thnx!Actually my problem is i have keep my gameobject gun in gameobject firstpersoncharacter which is in fpscontroller(as all do).But when i move my mouse in up and down gun is moving in y axis its not constant with firstpersoncharacter camera.

Comment: if its a scaling issue set the scale of the parent object to [1 1 1  click here](https://i.imgur.com/aV2GRij.png)
otherwise you may need to provide me a video or screenshots